# allow php files to write to locations other than those owned by www-data

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I am able to write content from a php file opened in the browser to a certain location `/var/www/data` which I configured as follows

```
cd /var/www/
sudo mkdir data
sudo chown www-data:www-data data
sudo chmod 755 data
```

However, is it possible to write similar data to another location like `/var/www/html/MyProjectRootFolder` which is not owned by www-data ?

Comment: Probably possible if you set up the permissions correctly, like you did with you data folder. But it's not a good practice to do that.

Comment: @kenhkelly, I want my ajax call to read from a file. Due to security reasons, AJAX is not allowed to read from any file that is outside the root of the application. So, although, I'm able to write to /var/www/data, I now want to write a folder within my application like, say, /var/www/html/MyProjectRootFolder/data which can be accessible by my AJAX call.

Comment: You should be able to do it using absolute paths and setting up your file permissions correctly.

Comment: @kenhkelly, Which part? Are you saying that I can get AJAX to read from a file outside of the application's root folder by giving it an absolute path? I did try it, but wasn't able to, and read later that it's disabled for security reasons.

Comment: No, you would have to have a php file in your project folder that reads and writes the content to another location in the system. The AJAX would talk to the php file in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the web server's configuration is not going to allow applications to write to folders outside of their own Doc root. However, you could do something like symlink `/var/www/html/MyProjectRootFolder` to a location like `/var/www/data` within your Doc root that the application already *can* write to.

Depending, you may also need to make sure that the web server user still has read permissions to the symlinked content, or that won't work either.

Comment: I think what I'll do is, write a php file which would read from /var/www/data and echo it. Then write an AJAX call which would talk to this php file, in effect getting data from /var/www/data.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
sudo usermod -aG www-data username
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).