# How to create or edit files that not owned or grouped by www-data, without changing owner or group?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, embedded-linux, file-permissions

My PHP script create a ssh key pair and safe (file_put_contents) it to `/home/pi/.ssh/.`
This script works fine from command line.
But executing it from website (as **www-data** user) fails: 
"Warning: file_put_contents(`/home/pi/.ssh/...`) failed to open stream: Permission denied".

I don't want to change files group or owner. (i tried for tests and it works).

I don't want to use an extra scipt for this file editing.

I saw this question:
[allow php files to write to locations other than those owned by www-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037874/allow-php-files-to-write-to-locations-other-than-those-owned-by-www-data)
This solution is not what i was looking for.

I tried to add the path (`/home/pi/.ssh/`) and path+filname to `/etc/sudoers`.
This not working. It seems that sudoers is for executable files only?!

I would wish a solution like an entry in `/etc/sudoers`.
Because there will be some more files "outside the webserver" that needed to edit from website.

So please tell me, is there another easy option?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds like a super dangerous thing.

If you have access to the server, maybe you can trying using PHP to simply trigger the creation of the SSH key pair. Then a script on the server (a cront job for example) will create the key using root permission for example, then place then in a folder that PHP has access to.

What I am trying to say is to simply delegate that task to another script that has more privilege than www-data.